# XMLHttpRequest send() from local file returns undefined with Workers

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

I got a problem by handling with workers, when i make my request the `XMLHttpRequest()` send returns `null`, but the `onload` method returns the file which i expected when i call send. What am I doing wrong?
Here's the code:

```
function pegarDados(){
    let requisicao = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requisicao.overrideMimeType('text/plain'); 
    requisicao.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'JSONHttpRequest');
    requisicao.open('GET','./assets/data/dados.json', false);
    requisicao.onload = function(){
        return JSON.parse(this.response);
    };  
    let resultado = requisicao.send();
    return resultado.responseText;   
}
self.onmessage = function (event) {
    if(event.data == 'lista'){
        let dados = pegarDados();
        console.error(dados);
        self.postMessage(dados);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`XMLHttpRequest.send()`actually has a return value of `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).

In your code, you are trying to assign the set the value of your request by doing:

`let resultado = requisicao.send();`

which would obviously assign `undefined` to the variable.

What you were doing with `xhr.onload` is what I would do too, I don't really see why you want to have two return methods.

Looking as you made your xhr not asynchronous, you could just do:

```
requisciao.send();
return requisciao.responseText;
```

Comment: Thank you! It was exactly that, i feel kind dummy. But you are awesome!